# Random Narrator in Windows 10 (Narrator is switched OFF)

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, narrator

OMG. Narrator is driving me crazy.
Spent a few days now googling and it seems it has something to do with either Chrome or a background process.
Narrator is definitely switched off.

I even tried deleting the Narrator app at one point but I think Windows reinstalls it.

What happens is I will randomly hear the Narrator(malevoice) read new posts in tabs I have open.
When this happens I do not see the narrator app in my taskbar.
I tried using the Windows + CTRL + Enter keyboard combination but it has no effect.

I've given up for the time being.